# Change windows narration (voiceover) selection for input radio

Tags: html, voiceover

I have the following html code, which contains input radio and label for it, when I turn windows narration (voiceover) on, it highlights only radio button:

[image]

But, I want input + label to be highlighted together:

[image]

is there any way to achieve this?

Here's my code:

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio1" checked>
    <label for="radio1">
        Field label
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overcame the issue by changing markup a bit. I added wrapper div:

```
<div class="radio-wrapper">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio1" checked>
    <label for="radio1">
        Field label
    </label>
</div>
```

And made radio button width & height `100%` and `display: inline-block;`

Now it's acting as it should.